# Export nested xml from MS access with filters on multiple tables

Tags: xml, vba, ms-access

I am trying to export a number of tables from an MS access database to a nested xml file. The tables contain all the data in my database, but I need the xml file to contain only the Journal, Volume and Issue values that the user inputs. The data for Journal, Volume and Issue values are stored in separate tables.

So far, I have been able to export nested xml with a WhereCondition for the tblJournal table, which allows the user to select only one journal (using a text box "txtJournal"), but I need to be able to simultaneously filter by Volume and Issue numbers using "txtVolume" and "txtIssue".

This is what I have so far:

```
Dim objVolumes As AdditionalData, objIssues As AdditionalData, objArticles As AdditionalData, objColour As AdditionalData, objESM As AdditionalData

Set objVolumes = Application.CreateAdditionalData

' Add the Vol, Iss, Article, colour and ESM tables to the data to be exported.

Set objIssues = objVolumes.Add("tblVolumes")
Set objArticles = objIssues.Add("tblIssues")
Set objColour = objArticles.Add("tblArticles")
Set objESM = objArticles.Add("tblArticles")
objColour.Add "tblColour"
objESM.Add "tblESM"

Application.ExportXML _
        ObjectType:=acExportTable, _
        DataSource:="tblJournals", _
        DataTarget:="C:\Users\TomL\Desktop\IssueData.xml", _
        WhereCondition:="Journal= '" & Me.txtJournal & "'", _
        AdditionalData:=objVolumes
End Sub
```

Any help would be really appreciated! Here is an overview of the [Database relationships](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDX3p.jpg) I have set up.

Comment: _"I am trying to export ... to a nested xml file"_ -- This really isn't enough information. Nested how?  What is the relationship of the data? Can you create a view that contains the required data and export that? Please visit the [help] and read [ask].

Comment: Hi Jim, thanks for you response. Journal is the top-level tag, within which sits multiple volumes. In each volume there are multiple issues, and within each issue there are multiple articles. Each article has multiple colour and ESM data associated with them. My database has these relationships setup with Journals providing the foreign key for Volumes, Volumes providing the key for Issues etc. The problem is that i can filter by journal, but then all the volumes, issues, articles are exported too, whereas I need to filter not only on journal, but also on Volume and issue.